# "I didn't know Ed was Welsh" or "I didn't know Ed is Welsh"?

Tags: past-simple

I came across these two sentences and asked myself whether I could always use both versions:

> I didn't know Ed was Welsh.
>   Did you know that Cliff's wife is Canadian?

Both relates to someone's nationality. I assume both people still live. So could I say I didn't know Ed is Welsh? Or as I know now - do I have to use the simple past (was) here?

Comment: Technically you should say "I didn't know Ed is Welsh" because although you not knowing is a past event, Ed is presumably still Welsh and hasn't become South African while you weren't looking. Most people would use "was" though to avoid switching tense, I think.

Comment: Oh thank you Usernew! I should proof read my comments before I post them! Sorry. How can I mark sentences in yellow?

Comment: Thanks John Clifford! I read it (both sentences) in a book on English vocab. Still, I wondered the usage.

Comment: To answer your other question, it's a blockquote: You can insert one by starting the line with ">".

Comment: Look through this [similar question.](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/283290/i-didnt-know-he-is-was) You use greater-than sign to quote, ">". You can use both, but it is preferable to go with the same tense, i.e. using "was."

Comment: Either one. Native speakers use *was* here all the time. *Was* here does not mean that Ed is no longer Welsh unless you say that directly. Consider: *I didn't know 2 plus 2 was 4.* You are reporting on a past state of knowledge, so it's okay to use *was*. You can use *is* if what you are saying is still true at the time you say it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Mixing present and past* happens in some occassions. You *can* use *present simple* instead of a *past tense* when something is *permanently true* as in

> He taught me that knowledge is power.
>
> He told me the Earth goes round the sun.
>
> He said he loves icecream.

In your example also if the guy said that he was Welsh, he's still Welsh I suppose at least till next time that I see him to make sure he's still Welsh or has taken refuge in another country to be the national of that country.

You can use both sentences then:

> I didn't know Ed was Welsh.
>
> I didn't know Ed is Welsh.