# If I told her I love/loved her now, she'd probably not take it seriously. ---- Usage of reported speech

Tags: tense, grammaticality, reported-speech

If I told her I **love** her now, she'd probably not take it seriously.

If I told her I **loved** her now, she'd probably not take it seriously.

In the above sentences the speaker loves the person they're talking about as of the present, so i was wondering whether both the sentences would be applicable in this context, and whether both of them could be deemed grammatically correct.

Comment: This question was already asked see http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/86060/i-didnt-know-ed-was-welsh-or-i-didnt-know-ed-is-welsh

Comment: Also here http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/53444/should-i-be-using-is-or-was-in-reported-speech

Comment: Just one point, if I _'told'_ her ..., she would take.... _'Told'_ is your main verb in your if clause not _love_. To avoid confusion, I think you should use 'love' not 'loved' because you're stating a fact that is true at the present time. Consider _if I told her that I **loved** her (once), she wouldnot take it seriously_ here you say you **no longer love** her. The rest can be found at the link in my previous comment. Good luck

Comment: @Yuri: But native speakers often backshift to past-tense in "reported speech" contexts.  If the meaning was that the love was a thing of the past (no longer true) it would be "If I told her **I'd** loved her..."  that is, "(that) I **had loved** her..."

Comment: Actually I assumed because of the fact that we use second conditional for unreal present situation, we can use present form of _love_ instead of past form i.e. _loved_  because we are talking about a fact that is still true. Apart from that in many cases native speakers use _simple past tense_ instead of _past perfect_ with no change in meaning.

Comment: @Yuri The  simple past tense *form* does not always refer to past time. In such uses as reported speech and whatever vestiges of the subjunctive remain, the past tense form is used to refer to present time. *If I were you (but I'm not), I wouldn't do that.*

Comment: Yea, but I thought maybe this is not true about an embedded sentence. "I loved/love her" is an embedded sentence which states a fact. _If I told you the earth **went/goes** round the sun_, I thought maybe because we're talking about a fact as an embedded sentence we can avoid going one tense back.

Comment: Does that make sense or sound weird? I'm not sure! I need a native speaker to tell me that.

Comment: The truth of the statement is not at issue: *I told her the earth was flat. I told her the earth was a sphere.*  We use **was** there not because of any unreality but because of "told".

Comment: @ TRomano & AlanCarmack  you are saying "I told her the earth _is_ a sphere" is a grammatical error and it must be _was_. Am I right?

Comment: @TRomano In ESL we used to teach that back-shifting was unnecessary in some cases. http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/reported-speech-indirect-speech

Comment: No, I wouldn't classify it as "grammatical error" at all. But its emphasis is on what was told rather than on the fact that it was told. It's almost a self-quoting:  I said to her, "the earth is a sphere".  It uses the verb **told** in a lax manner.

Comment: @Yuri Backshifting is optional in that example, as it often is.  That doesn't mean the odds of doing so are 50/50, just that both forms are okay.

Comment: @ TRomano & snailboat Oh, I see. Then when we don't do backshifting we emphasize that something is a current phenomenon but when we do, we simply report something was told or asked. (I know the general rules of backshifting though) Technically both are correct. I hope I got it right now. Thank you all ☺

Comment: Backshift marks the statement as one already spoken. as speech that is being *reported*.  *I was present when Joe said she was a good singer.*   Joe did not say "was". Joe said "is". Joe said, "She is a good singer."

Comment: @TRomano, So..should i take it that both the sentences i used are grammatically correct and the only difference between them is in the first sentence, i'm putting more emphasis on how the speaker told how they loved her, whereas in the second one i'm putting more emphasis on how the speaker loves her now. 
Am i wrong?

Comment: By the way, people usually say "she probably wouldn't take it seriously" rather than "she'd probably not take it seriously".

Answer (score 1):

Some speakers backshift with indirect or reported speech.

**I told her I *loved* her.**

Some do not.

**I told her I *love* her.**

A speaker who normally backshifts, when he does not backshift, may be putting some additional emphasis on the actual words spoken, for whatever reason, perhaps to indicate that they're still just as true now as they were when he said them, or to get even closer to the actual words spoken, approaching a direct quote.

**I told her that I *love* her.**

> What did he say to you at that meeting?
>   --He said I *was going* to regret my decision.

Of course, what he actually said was "You *are going* to regret your decision."